# Error in loading javascript file from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

[image: cannot load javascript file in local host]
I am trying to use node.js code to run the data in local host, but after I run the code, the javascript file that link inside the Admin Page.html is not running in localhost , and the font file src that wrote inside the Admin Page.html is also not running.How do i fix that? my javascript file is AdminPage.js

complete code for Admin Page.html and AdminPage.js is inside :
https://jsfiddle.net/szeYun/25x6bqLn/

```
var http =require('http');
var fs = require('fs');



var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if (req.url != '/favicon.ico'){
        console.log('The request made is: '+ req.url);

    }
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        //res.end('Hello World');
        var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + './Admin Page.html' , 'utf8');
        myReadStream.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Now the server is listenening on port 3000');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szeYun/25x6bqLn/

Comment: Using whitespaces in file names can cause problems. Try to rename your sourcefile to `AdminPage.html`

Comment: I'd use fs.readFileSync to read file content and then in callback of it you will have data or error, which you can simply send to a client

Comment: it still got the same error which Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in AdminPage.js, but I did not put the <!Doctype> inside AdminPage.js, I only put that inside html

Comment: In the createServer function callback you respond with `Admin Page.html` to any request except for favicon.ico. So when browser tries to load `AdminPage.js` you send back `Admin Page.html` which has `<!Doctype>` in it.